# usbip - Webcam - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I want to use the webcam of my Laptop as if it would be connected to my pc.

Specs:
Ubuntu Mate 18.04
Kernel Client: 5.3.0-46-generic
Kernel Server: 4.15.0-96-generic
USBIP Version: 4.15.0-96-generic

This are the Error Messages.

usbip port

```
usbip: error: failed to open /usr/share/hwdata//usb.ids
usbip: error: open vhci_driver
usbip: error: list imported devices
```

This is what happen,when i attach the device:

sudo usbip --debug attach -r 192.168.2.22 -b 1-1.6

```
usbip: debug: usbip.c:129:[run_command] running command: `attach'
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:269:[usbip_vhci_driver_open] available ports: 16
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:281:[usbip_vhci_driver_open] available controllers: 1
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:128:[refresh_imported_device_list] controller 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 0 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 1 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 2 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 3 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 4 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 5 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 6 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub hs port 7 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 8 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 9 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 10 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 11 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 12 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 13 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 14 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:68:[parse_status] hub ss port 15 status 4 speed 0 devid 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:69:[parse_status] sockfd 0 lbusid 0-0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:104:[parse_status] exit
usbip: debug: usbip_attach.c:100:[import_device] got free port 0
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:367:[usbip_vhci_attach_device2] writing: 0 3 65540 3
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:372:[usbip_vhci_attach_device2] attach attribute path: /sys/devices/platform/vhci_hcd.0/attach
libusbip: debug: vhci_driver.c:380:[usbip_vhci_attach_device2] attached port: 0
```

/var/log/syslog client

```
Apr  8 12:42:32 client kernel: [ 7376.482998] vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: pdev(0) rhport(0) sockfd(3)
Apr  8 12:42:32 client kernel: [ 7376.483003] vhci_hcd vhci_hcd.0: devid(65540) speed(3) speed_str(high-speed)
Apr  8 12:42:32 client kernel: [ 7376.726204] usb 5-1: new high-speed USB device number 18 using vhci_hcd
Apr  8 12:42:32 client kernel: [ 7376.726212] usb 5-1: SetAddress Request (18) to port 0
Apr  8 12:42:32 client kernel: [ 7376.803460] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Apr  8 12:42:32 client kernel: [ 7377.002279] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
Apr  8 12:42:33 client kernel: [ 7378.010236] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Apr  8 12:42:33 client kernel: [ 7378.010253] usb usb5-port1: attempt power cycle
Apr  8 12:42:34 client kernel: [ 7379.234242] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Apr  8 12:42:35 client kernel: [ 7380.138258] usb usb5-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Apr  8 12:42:35 client kernel: [ 7380.138276] usb usb5-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

/var/log/syslog server

```
Apr  8 12:42:32 server usbipd: usbipd: info: connection from 192.168.2.20:34330
Apr  8 12:42:32 server usbipd: usbipd: info: received request: 0x8003(6)
Apr  8 12:42:32 server usbipd: usbipd: info: found requested device: 1-1.6
Apr  8 12:42:32 server usbipd: usbip: info: connect: 1-1.6
Apr  8 12:42:32 server usbipd: usbipd: info: request 0x8003(6): complete
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.400594] usbip-host 1-1.6: stub up
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.710050] usbip-host 1-1.6: urb completion with non-zero status -71
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.716793] usbip-host 1-1.6: urb completion with non-zero status -71
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.722043] usbip-host 1-1.6: urb completion with non-zero status -71
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.909299] usbip-host 1-1.6: urb completion with non-zero status -71
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.915669] usbip-host 1-1.6: urb completion with non-zero status -71
Apr  8 12:42:32 server kernel: [ 9504.920794] usbip-host 1-1.6: urb completion with non-zero status -71
```